Locate and/or reinstall link to MS Query in Excel 365
I have a small data querying and analysis team that uses Microsoft Query to pull data from an ODBC connection. We are running Microsoft 365 and tapping into data sources inside Excel. The ODBC data source is 32-bit, so our install is 32-bit.
Primarily, we update and refresh existing sources, but we noticed in the last week that the access to Microsoft Query from the menu seems to be missing (seems removed).
Here's the investigation we've done so far.

Using what seems to be the current article for using MS Query, we are trying to use the menu option of Get Data > From Other Sources > Microsoft Query. The Microsoft Query option is no longer there.
Link: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-microsoft-query-to-retrieve-external-data-42a2ea18-44d9-40b3-9c38-4c62f252da2e

Excel Options > Customize Ribbon > All Commands > From Microsoft Query isn't available.
Open Excel in safe mode.

Review Excel add-ins, looking for disabled add-ins.


I have also scrubbed Office and installed Office 2016 and Office 365 fresh (not at the same time). In these tests, the options are still in place in Office 2016 (slightly different menu path -> Data tab > From Other Sources > From MS Query) but not in Office 365.
I realize I can still connect to the ODBC data source (Sybase ODBC driver) using PowerQuery, but Microsoft Query has been a useful tool to initially design queries and get raw data, then transform it in PowerQuery.
Any comments, knowledge, or fixes are welcome.

Microsoft Query has been deprecated in Excel, but not removed quite yet. You can re-add it to the ribbon by navigating to File > Options > Data > Show legacy data import wizards > Enable "From Microsoft Query (Legacy)"

It may be removed entirely in the future, so they recommend adjusting your workflow. My preference is Native Database Query for quick stuff, but it's not one size fits all.

Do you think that woould that also be true for Office 2021 LTSC? We are on the cusp of a corporate buy to replace Office 2016.

@Mark Not sure - it depends on when it was moved to legacy data import wizards. Office 2021 is generally the same as Office 365, but only 365 gets feature updates. LTSC has a bunch of additional limitations, see the note here, and it's generally used in environments where the device will never connect to the internet.

Thank you. This also solved one of my customer's problems.
